# Random Javascript and typescript file content changes to weird characters, leads to compilation failure

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm-install, nrwl

In my project, randomly JavaScript files content in `node_modules` getting changed to weird characters. If I do clear `node_modules` and `npm i` again then it works fine.
I am facing this issue frequently and consuming significant time of mine.

I tried checking the charset, this weird content file shows encoding as ANSI in notepad++. It didn't help  even I changed the encoding to UTF-8. Windows is updated to latest and also tried re-installing git, nothing helped.

I noticed that not same js files I face problem with, totally random it is. Also I have faced problem with random typescript file as well.
**Same codebase however working fine for all other developers on their machine.**

```
My machine Details:
OS: Windows 10    
Git: 2.31.1.windows.1
node: 10.23.0
Tortoise git: 2.12.0.0
```

**Here is file content:**

```
node_modules\@nrwl\cli\lib\output.js
```

```js
$œ’m…Îmo“LÒDüÜ;˜%gÏ?wêÁÅ·øîùovH0õÉa‡5£Ú*î Ø’ÃÌlÍ››S iyä”rÕO7ª“ž%L]Ý×%±ºÇhk ¶«·÷>v1­HB£®±ßÞÚd\(eoIx¢>3´6BS%ÌØá“(
œÛf$Ãhýé¿¶åeÔŽôÚèHœ‚`Ý¶f{Fo©Yò¿Ôó@00uMb’z-ëìXI$&ÂgfÖú¶7Ó´Þu|'K.ÌoP
PÝÀùFË.Ðýoûò9B<~. ’ïÅË[’´˜Ë<Ù­„$¯•¢·ä{1¹A•.òbKxºL ¯Ý·'¯u8n5 ’ºe ,]ñH©–’ÆV¨ŒWwÃ$ùCƒel¹“|zys«™KŠi-ðqÊÝ¬bk,wnGÿâ;¥  ~ÖeÉrÍ’‰ÜÔ~'1`Vâ¦«¹-*[ÉñLÔKÄ'2@ŸÜþÐä»ª ²n‘Íß2¸Nß ˆÆ¶µG•¢ói/U¢µ'Eï@¦`Hæ¹˜;J•¼¼ÜŽÅ+Jén#»¼‚6Ú´—Ä¹G•ü¡NÒGð'—Z!öáí¸‰Wi»NJ @óàšAûÜZ|ª[¨ï$q}iÒ·µQbtTEC$œ’m…Îmo“LÒDüÜ;˜%gÏ?wêÁÅ·øîùovH0õÉa‡5£Ú*î Ø’ÃÌlÍ››S iyä”rÕO7ª“ž%L]Ý×%±ºÇhk ¶«·÷>v1­HB£®±ßÞÚd\(eoIx¢>3´6BS%ÌØá“(
œÛf$Ãhýé¿¶åeÔŽôÚèHœ‚`Ý¶f{Fo©Yò¿Ôó@00uMb’z-ëìXI$&ÂgfÖú¶7Ó´Þu|'K.ÌoP
PÝÀùFË.Ðýoûò9B<~. ’ïÅË[’´˜Ë<Ù­„$¯•¢·ä{1¹A•.òbKxºL ¯Ý·'¯u8n5 ’ºe ,]ñH©–’ÆV¨ŒWwÃ$ùCƒel¹“|zys«™KŠi-ðqÊÝ¬bk,wnGÿâ;¥  ~ÖeÉrÍ’‰ÜÔ~'1`Vâ¦«¹-*[ÉñLÔKÄ'2@ŸÜþÐä»ª ²n‘Íß2¸Nß ˆÆ¶µG•¢ói/U¢µ'Eï@¦`Hæ¹˜;J•¼¼ÜŽÅ+Jén#»¼‚6Ú´—Ä¹G•ü¡NÒGð'—Z!öáí¸‰Wi»NJ @óàšAûÜZ|ª[¨ï$q}iÒ·µQbtTEC$œ’m…Îmo“LÒDüÜ;˜%gÏ?wêÁÅ·øîùovH0õÉa‡5£Ú*î Ø’ÃÌlÍ››S iyä”rÕO7ª“ž%L]Ý×%±ºÇhk ¶«·÷>v1­HB£®±ßÞÚd\(eoIx¢>3´6BS%ÌØá“(
œÛf$Ãhýé¿¶åeÔŽôÚèHœ‚`Ý¶f{Fo©Yò¿Ôó@00uMb’z-ëìXI$&ÂgfÖú¶7Ó´Þu|'K.ÌoP
PÝÀùFË.Ðýoûò9B<~. ’ïÅË[’´˜Ë<Ù­„$¯•¢·ä{1¹A•.òbKxºL ¯Ý·'¯u8n5 ’ºe ,]ñH©–’ÆV¨ŒWwÃ$ùCƒel¹“|zys«™KŠi-ðqÊÝ¬bk,wnGÿâ;¥  ~ÖeÉrÍ’‰ÜÔ~'1`Vâ¦«¹-*[ÉñLÔKÄ'2@ŸÜþÐä»ª ²n‘Íß2¸Nß ˆÆ¶µG•¢ói/U¢µ'Eï@¦`Hæ¹˜;J•¼¼ÜŽÅ+Jén#»¼‚6Ú´—Ä¹G•ü¡NÒGð'—Z!öáí¸‰Wi»NJ @óàšAûÜZ|ª[¨ï$q}iÒ·µQbtTEC$œ’m…Îmo“LÒDüÜ;˜%gÏ?wêÁÅ·øîùovH0õÉa‡5£Ú*î Ø’ÃÌlÍ››S iyä”rÕO7ª“ž%L]Ý×%±ºÇhk ¶«·÷>v1­HB£®±ßÞÚd\(eoIx¢>3´6BS%ÌØá“(
œÛf$Ãhýé¿¶åeÔŽôÚèHœ‚`Ý¶f{Fo©Yò¿Ôó@00uMb’z-ëìXI$&ÂgfÖú¶7Ó´Þu|'K.ÌoP
PÝÀùFË.Ðýoûò9B<~. ’ïÅË[’´˜Ë<Ù­„$¯•¢·ä{1¹A•.òbKxºL ¯Ý·'¯u8n5 ’ºe ,]ñH©–’ÆV¨ŒWwÃ$ùCƒel¹“|zys«™KŠi-ðqÊÝ¬bk,wnGÿâ;¥  ~ÖeÉrÍ’‰ÜÔ~'1`Vâ¦«¹-*[ÉñLÔKÄ'2@ŸÜþÐä»ª ²n‘Íß2¸Nß ˆÆ¶µG•¢ói/U¢µ'Eï@¦`Hæ¹˜;J•¼¼ÜŽÅ+Jén#»¼‚6Ú´—Ä¹G•ü¡NÒGð'—Z!öáí¸‰Wi»NJ @óàšAûÜZ|ª[¨ï$q}iÒ·µQbtTEC$œ’m…Îmo“LÒDüÜ;˜%gÏ?wêÁÅ·øîùovH0õÉa‡5£Ú*î Ø’ÃÌlÍ››S iyä”rÕO7ª“ž%L]Ý×%±ºÇhk ¶«·÷>v1­HB£®±ßÞÚd\(eoIx¢>3´6BS%ÌØá“(
œÛf$Ãhýé¿¶åeÔŽôÚèHœ‚`Ý¶f{Fo©Yò¿Ôó@00uMb’z-ëìXI$&ÂgfÖú¶7Ó´Þu|'K.ÌoP
PÝÀùFË.Ðýoûò9B<~. ’ïÅË[’´˜Ë<Ù­„$¯•¢·ä{1¹A•.òbKxºL ¯Ý·'¯u8n5 ’ºe ,]ñH©–’ÆV¨ŒWwÃ$ùCƒel¹“|zys«™KŠi-ðqÊÝ¬bk,wnGÿâ;¥  ~ÖeÉrÍ’‰ÜÔ~'1`Vâ¦«¹-*[ÉñLÔKÄ'2@ŸÜþÐä»ª ²n‘Íß2¸Nß ˆÆ¶µG•¢ói/U¢µ'Eï@¦`Hæ¹˜;J•¼¼ÜŽÅ+Jén#»¼‚6Ú´—Ä¹G•ü¡NÒGð'—Z!öáí¸‰Wi»NJ @óàšAûÜZ|ª[¨ï$q}iÒ·µQbtTEC$œ’m…Îmo“LÒDüÜ;˜%gÏ?wêÁÅ·øîùovH0õÉa‡5£Ú*î Ø’ÃÌlÍ››S iyä”rÕO7ª“ž%L]Ý×%±ºÇhk ¶«·÷>v1­HB£®±ßÞÚd\(eoIx¢>3´6BS%ÌØá“(
œÛf$Ãhýé¿¶åeÔŽôÚèHœ‚`Ý¶f{Fo©Yò¿Ôó@00uMb’z-ëìXI$&ÂgfÖú¶7Ó´Þu|'K.ÌoP
PÝÀùFË.Ðýoûò9B<~. ’ïÅË[’´˜Ë<Ù­„$¯•¢·ä{1¹A•.òbKxºL ¯Ý·'¯u8n5 ’ºe ,]ñH©–’ÆV¨ŒWwÃ$ùCƒel¹“|zys«™KŠi-ðqÊÝ¬bk,wnGÿâ;¥  ~ÖeÉrÍ’‰ÜÔ~'1`Vâ¦«¹-*[ÉñLÔKÄ'2@ŸÜþÐä»ª ²n‘Íß2¸Nß ˆÆ¶µG•¢ói/U¢µ'Eï@¦`Hæ¹˜;J•¼¼ÜŽÅ+Jén#»¼‚6Ú´—Ä¹G•ü¡NÒGð'—Z!öáí¸‰Wi»NJ @óàšAûÜZ|ª[¨ï$q}iÒ·µQbtTEC$œ’m…Îmo“LÒDüÜ;˜%gÏ?wêÁÅ·øîùovH0õÉa‡5£Ú*î Ø’ÃÌlÍ››S iyä”rÕO7ª“ž%L]Ý×%±ºÇhk ¶«·÷>v1­HB£®±ßÞÚd\(eoIx¢>3´6BS%ÌØá“(
œÛf$Ãhýé¿¶åeÔŽôÚèHœ‚`Ý¶f{Fo©Yò¿Ôó@00uMb’z-ëìXI$&ÂgfÖú¶7Ó´Þu|'K.ÌoP
PÝÀùFË.Ðýoûò9B<~. ’ïÅË[’´˜Ë<Ù­„$¯•¢·ä{1¹A•.òbKxºL ¯Ý·'¯u8n5 ’ºe ,]ñH©–’ÆV¨ŒWwÃ$ùCƒel¹“|zys«™KŠi-ðqÊÝ¬bk,wnGÿâ;¥  ~ÖeÉrÍ’‰ÜÔ~'1`Vâ¦«¹-*[ÉñLÔKÄ'2@ŸÜþÐä»ª ²n‘Íß2¸Nß ˆÆ¶µG•¢ói/U¢µ'Eï@¦`Hæ¹˜;J•¼¼ÜŽÅ+Jén#»¼‚6Ú´—Ä¹G•ü¡NÒGð'—Z!öáí¸‰Wi»NJ @óàšAûÜZ|ª[¨ï$q}iÒ·µQbtTEC$œ’m…Îmo“LÒDüÜ;˜%gÏ?wêÁÅ·øîùovH0õÉa‡5£Ú*î Ø’ÃÌlÍ››S iyä”rÕO7ª“ž%L]Ý×%±ºÇhk ¶«·÷>v1­HB£®±ßÞÚd\(eoIx¢>3´6BS%ÌØá“(
œÛf$Ãhýé¿¶åeÔŽôÚèHœ‚`Ý¶f{Fo©Yò¿Ôó@00uMb’z-ëìXI$&ÂgfÖú¶7Ó´Þu|'K.ÌoP
PÝÀùFË.Ðýoûò9B<~. ’ïÅË[’´˜Ë<Ù­„$¯•¢·ä{1¹A•.òbKxºL ¯Ý·'¯u8n5 ’ºe ,]ñH©–’ÆV¨ŒWwÃ$ùCƒel¹“|zys«™KŠi-ðqÊÝ¬bk,wnGÿâ;¥  ~ÖeÉrÍ’‰ÜÔ~'1`Vâ¦«¹-*[ÉñLÔKÄ'2@ŸÜþÐä»ª ²n‘Íß2¸Nß ˆÆ¶µG•¢ói/U¢µ'Eï@¦`Hæ¹˜;J•¼¼ÜŽÅ+Jén#»¼‚6Ú´—Ä¹G•ü¡NÒGð'—Z!öáí¸‰Wi»NJ @óàšAûÜZ|ª[¨ï$q}iÒ·µQbtTEC$œ’m…Îmo“LÒDüÜ;˜%gÏ?wêÁÅ·øîùovH0õÉa‡5£Ú*î Ø’ÃÌlÍ››S iyä”rÕO7ª“ž%L]Ý×%±ºÇhk ¶«·÷>v1­HB£®±ßÞÚd\(eoIx¢>3´6BS%ÌØá“(
œÛf$Ãhýé¿¶åeÔŽôÚèHœ‚`Ý¶f{Fo©Yò¿Ôó@00uMb’z-ëìXI$&ÂgfÖú¶7Ó´Þu|'K.ÌoP
PÝÀùFË.Ðýoûò9B<~. ’ïÅË[’´˜Ë<Ù­„$¯•¢·ä{1¹A•.òbKxºL ¯Ý·'¯u8n5 ’ºe ,]ñH©–’ÆV¨ŒWwÃ$ùCƒel¹“|zys«™KŠi-ðqÊÝ¬bk,wnGÿâ;¥  ~ÖeÉrÍ’‰ÜÔ~'1`Vâ¦«¹-*[ÉñLÔKÄ'2@ŸÜþÐä»ª ²n‘Íß2¸Nß ˆÆ¶µG•¢ói/U¢µ'Eï@¦`Hæ¹˜;J•¼¼ÜŽÅ+Jén#»¼‚6Ú´—Ä¹G•ü¡NÒGð'—Z!öáí¸
```

[image]

**Code compilation output**

```
$→œ’m…Îmo“LÒDüÜ;˜%gÏ?wêÁÅ·↓ø▬îùovH0õÉa‡5£Ú*î Ø’ÃÌlÍ››S iy☺ä”rÕO7ª“ž%L]Ý×%±º∟Çhk ¶«·÷>v1­HB£®±♣ßÞÚd\(‼e♂o▼Ix¢>3´☺6BS%ÌØá“(⌂
 ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\A_UI_ionTrader\ngIonTrader\ionTrader\node_modules\@nrwl\cli\lib\init-global.js:6:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
```

Please help.

Comment: Not sure but things that came to mind, in case they help:  Have you maybe hit the Windows filename size limit? Are you doing any funny business with Window's Linux subsystem, and they're fighting over the same file?  Is this a binary file which just happens to have a .js extension? Gzipped?

Comment: not all the files in same folder are affected, only two of them. These files are not binary they are javascript file only. Regarding windows's linux subsystem, i dont think these should be fighting, is there a way to be sure about this?

Comment: This is very peculiar.  I'm afraid I don't know what's up.  It's always these same files going funny?  Is there a moment in time where they're plaintext and then they scramble after some delay?   I suspect it's something at the OS level. Encrypted hard drive, indexing?  After long enough, do more files do this? Is there some sort of compiler/transpiler that's accidentally processing these files in-place?  If you're doing TypeScript/`tsc` or Webpack, make sure they're not crawling the `node_modules` folder.  Funny enough, I can't @ you.  I suspect it thinks your name is controversial :)

Comment: It happened to me too on some php files and innodb table files, and if you do a search with some of words in the text you can see sites that are facing the same problem... Do you resolved your issue?
Here an example online: https://revistaelcrisol.com/
We got all same stranges words inside